# Flex Grid View for List

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I need component that can display a list/collection of items in a Grid View (the DataGrid is not what I am looking),what I want to do is display a Grid with Images, and this component must do ItemRenderer recycling so if I have 100 or more images in my list I don't get a renderer(so more of100 total) for each image.
Is something like this already build ?I can't find it , I would prefer to not reinvent it.
For more clarity, I need something like this http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt-maemo/declarative-modelviews-gridview.html  not a image gallery with a large image on top and some smaller preview images on bottom  , I need something like you would use for showing thumbnails in a file manager.
Thanks.

Comment: How about Tile List and setting the max rows or max column as in your case to 1.

Comment: @AdrianPirvulescu yes, that seems right , can you add this as a response and I will accept it, I did not think to search for Tile so my queries were using the term grid

Comment: Happy flexing, thanks for marking the asnwer as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about Tile List and setting the max rows or max column as in your case to 1